# Running multiple VMs in one large EC2 ( para or HVM ) instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

How to install multiple VMs in one large EC2 ( para or HVM ) instance ?

Comment: Have you found any concrete solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is one use of EC2 that may not work very well. All EC2 instances are already virtual machines based on Xen. You would essentially be running a VM within a VM.

Comment: I have came across few articles which have suggested methods for creating virtual machines using OpenVZ. 
Have you looked at them?
Can you help me in understanding what type of complication this can cause for us in the production environment looking at the performance charts.